# How to make verifiable all methods with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

To verify that method was called we should make this method verifiable:

```
// arrange
mock
    .Setup(foo => foo.SomeMethod("param1", "param2", "param3", "param4"))
    .Verifiable();
```

And then we can do this:

```
// assert
mock
    .Verify(foo => foo.SomeMethod("param1", "param2", "param3", "param4"));
```

I want avoid this duplicate code... In case of complex test the code becomes overloaded and unreadable.

So my question is how to make verifiable all methods (with any parameters) in arrange section?

### Note

I know about `VerifyAll()`:

```
// assert
mock.VerifyAll();
```

But it has the drawback: it is not obvious what is actually verified. So I'm looking for some alternative.

Comment: Your arrange part is not needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a mock factory (see "Customizing Mock Behavior" [here](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart))

```
var factory = new MockFactory(MockBehavior.Strict) { DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock };

var fooMock = factory.Create<IFoo>();
var barMock = factory.Create<IBar>();

// Verify all verifiable expectations on all mocks created through the factory
factory.Verify();
```

**EDIT**

in your example you could even avoid using the setup since you're not setting up anything, no need to mark it as Verifiable. In short: delete the setup and keep the verify

Comment: I don't want verify all because it is not obvious what is actually verifying. Can I verify some specific method with some specific parameters with this approach?

Comment: @wishmaster: in your example you could even avoid using the setup since you're not setting up anything, no need to mark it as Verifiable. In short: delete the setup and keep the verify.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but instead of specifying the same parameters twice, you can use `It.IsAny<T>` to mean "any instance of this type".

e.g.

```
mock.Setup(foo => foo.SomeMethod(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()));

//act...

mock.Verify(foo => foo.SomeMethod("param1", "param2", "param3", "param4"));
```

This reduces possibility of duplicating method parameters but it does have a side effect of allowing any parameters of that type to match.

Also at the risk of sounding like an idiot, I want to point out that a unit test should never be that complex that you can't read it. If you find yourself using the same code in many unit tests, you should refactor the tests to make them smaller and more readable.